# why is this javascript alert firing off twice?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, alert, innerhtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeStyle()
{
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 
        "<a href='javascript:void()' onclick=\"window.location.href='http://google.com'\">The New Link</a>";
}
</script>
<a id="p1" href="javascript:void()" onclick="ChangeStyle();alert('hello');">The Link</a>
```

This is the full code. For some reason the alert fires off twice. I can't figure it out.

Comment: add the code where you are using ChangeStyle()

Comment: FYI, onclick calls come with `this` referencing the calling element. You don't need to find the element again with getElementById. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qHSvT/

Comment: You are putting a link in a link, are you just trying to replace it?

Answer (score 5):

By setting the `innerHTML` of the link, you're creating another link inside of first link.

When you click on this inner link, the click event bubbles and also fires the outer click handler.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, how will I prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to wrap your link into another element:

```
<span id="p1">
 <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="ChangeStyle();alert('hello');">The Link</a>
</span>
```

Now you can replace the contents of `p1` using `innerHTML` the way you probably intended:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeStyle()
{
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<a [...]>The New Link</a>";
}
</script>
```

Otherwise, you're creating a link inside of your link

Comment: THanks for showing me how it should have been written. I see my mistake now and what you mean by a link inside of another link. Thanks again for your post.